# Wordpress –– Someone using my admin email address / user name to send emails confirming fictitious registrations

Tags: wordpress

Here is their outging email.

---------- Forwarded message ----------
From: tomnora 
To: GcxwtJgnCTWXlhaq 
Cc: 
Bcc: 
Date: Tue, 17 Dec 2019 10:18:39 +0000
Subject: Confirm your subscription to TravlGusto
Hello!

Hurray! You've subscribed to our site.
We need you to activate your subscription to the list(s): My first list by clicking the link below:

Click here to confirm your subscription.

Thank you,

The team!

---

They get bounced, but why is this happening? How do I stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. Sending email means saying not only what you want to send and who you want to send it to, but also who you are. And you can say that you're anybody you want:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_spoofing

Comment: Thanks jirka.pinkas for answering. That's kind of sad, but I guess the way of the internet. I wonder why they picked one of my low activity websites to spoof.

Comment: Spammers sometimes do weird things. These emais are automatically generated, probably no human spammer even went to your website, their crawler can get your domain name from DNS server or some online directory. I wouldn’t search for logic here :-) It’s something we have to live with :-/